# Splitting dataframe depending on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Let's say you have the following data frame

```
set.seed(12345)
people <- data.frame(Name = paste("Name", 1:51),
                     Var1 = sample(c("A", "B"), 51, prob = c(0.3, 0.7), replace = TRUE),
                     Var2 = sample(1:2, 51, replace = TRUE))
table(people$Var1, people$Var2)

     1  2
  A 12  5
  B 21 13
```

I would like to split the dataset into groups depending on certain criteria.

For example, I might want to divide the dataset into 9 groups, so that each one has at least 1 person with `Var1 == 'A'` and a roughly equal balance between 1 and 2 for `Var2`.

Obviously, an exact split is not possible so, in this example, I would allocate 5 people to each group and then allocate the rest randomly, in order to have either 5 or 6 people in each group.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

PS: I am asking how to do this in R, as I already have these data in R, but a generic solution would be appreciated as well

Comment: Stratified sampling? This seems more appropriate to ask in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am purely asking about an algorithmic solution, so CrossValidated seems not appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach with `dplyr`:

- first order the dataset randomly
- then order by `Var1,Var2`
- select `n=9` first people (with `Var1 == 'A'` because of order)
- sort the remaining people by `Var2` and dispatch them in the groups

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 9

data <- people[sample(nrow(people),replace=F),] %>% arrange(Var1,Var2)

rbind(head(data, n) %>% mutate(grp = 1:n),
      tail(data,-n) %>% arrange(Var2) %>%
                        mutate(grp = rep(1:n,length.out=nrow(people)-n))
     ) %>% split(.$grp)

$`1`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
1  Name 43    A    1   1
10 Name 31    A    1   1
19 Name 22    B    1   1
28 Name 21    B    1   1
37 Name 23    A    2   1
46 Name 46    B    2   1

$`2`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
2   Name 4    A    1   2
11 Name 51    A    1   2
20 Name 17    B    1   2
29 Name 14    B    1   2
38 Name 37    A    2   2
47 Name 49    B    2   2

$`3`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
3   Name 3    A    1   3
12 Name 13    A    1   3
21  Name 5    B    1   3
30 Name 36    B    1   3
39 Name 11    B    2   3
48 Name 33    B    2   3

$`4`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
4  Name 10    A    1   4
13 Name 15    B    1   4
22 Name 47    B    1   4
31  Name 8    B    1   4
40 Name 42    B    2   4
49 Name 19    B    2   4

$`5`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
5   Name 1    A    1   5
14  Name 7    B    1   5
23 Name 34    B    1   5
32 Name 35    B    1   5
41 Name 26    B    2   5
50 Name 30    B    2   5

$`6`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
6  Name 41    A    1   6
15 Name 50    B    1   6
24 Name 29    B    1   6
33 Name 16    B    1   6
42 Name 48    B    2   6
51 Name 27    B    2   6

$`7`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
7   Name 9    A    1   7
16 Name 28    B    1   7
25 Name 40    B    1   7
34 Name 44    A    2   7
43 Name 45    B    2   7

$`8`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
8  Name 38    A    1   8
17 Name 32    B    1   8
26 Name 39    B    1   8
35 Name 20    A    2   8
44 Name 25    B    2   8

$`9`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
9  Name 24    A    1   9
18 Name 18    B    1   9
27  Name 6    B    1   9
36  Name 2    A    2   9
45 Name 12    B    2   9
```

Answer (score 4):

## Update

Here is an update which may fit your goal, where an algorithm like *water-filling* is applied to sample rows dynamically according to updated groups.

```
ngrp <- 9
dfa <- subset(people, Var1 == "A")
dfb <- subset(people, Var1 == "B")

dfa_gr <- transform(
  dfa,
  grp = ave(Var2, Var2, FUN = function(x) {
    sample(
      rep(seq(ngrp),
        length.out = length(x)
      ), length(x)
    )
  })
)

lst <- split(subset(dfa_gr, select = -grp), dfa_gr$grp)

while (nrow(dfb) > 0) {
  k <- which.min(sapply(lst, nrow))
  tofill <- c(1:2)[which.min(table(factor(lst[[k]]$Var2, levels = 1:2)))]
  vb <- subset(dfb, Var2 == tofill)
  if (nrow(vb) > 0) {
    rm <- sample(row.names(vb), 1)
  } else {
    rm <- sample(row.names(dfb), 1)
  }
  lst[[k]] <- rbind(lst[[k]], dfb[rm, ])
  dfb <- dfb[row.names(dfb) != rm, ]
}
```

which gives

```
> lst
$`1`
      Name Var1 Var2
2   Name 2    A    2
9   Name 9    A    1
51 Name 51    A    1
49 Name 49    B    2
21 Name 21    B    1
29 Name 29    B    1

$`2`
      Name Var1 Var2
1   Name 1    A    1
13 Name 13    A    1
20 Name 20    A    2
19 Name 19    B    2
14 Name 14    B    1
32 Name 32    B    1

$`3`
      Name Var1 Var2
10 Name 10    A    1
43 Name 43    A    1
44 Name 44    A    2
30 Name 30    B    2
36 Name 36    B    1
34 Name 34    B    1

$`4`
      Name Var1 Var2
3   Name 3    A    1
23 Name 23    A    2
7   Name 7    B    1
45 Name 45    B    2
6   Name 6    B    1
17 Name 17    B    1

$`5`
      Name Var1 Var2
37 Name 37    A    2
41 Name 41    A    1
40 Name 40    B    1
25 Name 25    B    2
16 Name 16    B    1
22 Name 22    B    1

$`6`
      Name Var1 Var2
31 Name 31    A    1
42 Name 42    B    2
15 Name 15    B    1
48 Name 48    B    2
35 Name 35    B    1
8   Name 8    B    1

$`7`
      Name Var1 Var2
24 Name 24    A    1
27 Name 27    B    2
28 Name 28    B    1
46 Name 46    B    2
50 Name 50    B    1

$`8`
      Name Var1 Var2
38 Name 38    A    1
33 Name 33    B    2
18 Name 18    B    1
26 Name 26    B    2
39 Name 39    B    1

$`9`
      Name Var1 Var2
4   Name 4    A    1
11 Name 11    B    2
47 Name 47    B    1
12 Name 12    B    2
5   Name 5    B    1
```

---

Here is an attempt to group rows randomly, which has at least one `Var1==A` in each group and tries to have close size among groups. However, I didn't get the meaning of this objective:

> roughly equal balance between 1 and 2 for `Var2`

You have uneven numbers of `1` and `2` so it seems difficulty to have even distribution of them. Or, could you explain a bit on that?

---

Below is one option, maybe close to your goal:

```
ngrp <- 9
z <- do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(
      with(people, split(people, Var1)),
      function(v) {
        v <- v[order(v$Var2), ]
        transform(
          v,
          grp = sample(
            rep(seq(ngrp),
              length.out = nrow(v)
            ), nrow(v)
          )
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
res <- with(z, split(z, grp))
```

which gives

```
> res
$`1`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
5  Name 10    A    1   1
7  Name 24    A    1   1
18  Name 5    B    1   1
19  Name 6    B    1   1
28 Name 22    B    1   1
48 Name 45    B    2   1

$`2`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
1   Name 1    A    1   2
12 Name 51    A    1   2
32 Name 34    B    1   2
34 Name 36    B    1   2
39 Name 11    B    2   2
41 Name 19    B    2   2

$`3`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
6  Name 13    A    1   3
17 Name 44    A    2   3
25 Name 17    B    1   3
29 Name 28    B    1   3
33 Name 35    B    1   3
49 Name 46    B    2   3

$`4`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
2   Name 3    A    1   4
14 Name 20    A    2   4
22 Name 14    B    1   4
35 Name 39    B    1   4
50 Name 48    B    2   4
51 Name 49    B    2   4

$`5`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
9  Name 38    A    1   5
15 Name 23    A    2   5
23 Name 15    B    1   5
27 Name 21    B    1   5
43 Name 26    B    2   5
44 Name 27    B    2   5

$`6`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
13  Name 2    A    2   6
16 Name 37    A    2   6
31 Name 32    B    1   6
37 Name 47    B    1   6
40 Name 12    B    2   6
47 Name 42    B    2   6

$`7`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
8  Name 31    A    1   7
10 Name 41    A    1   7
20  Name 7    B    1   7
30 Name 29    B    1   7
45 Name 30    B    2   7
46 Name 33    B    2   7

$`8`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
4   Name 9    A    1   8
11 Name 43    A    1   8
24 Name 16    B    1   8
38 Name 50    B    1   8
42 Name 25    B    2   8

$`9`
      Name Var1 Var2 grp
3   Name 4    A    1   9
21  Name 8    B    1   9
26 Name 18    B    1   9
36 Name 40    B    1   9
```

Comment: That looks good, I just need some time to "digest" the code! As for not being able to exactly have even distribution between 1 and 2... well that is exactly the issue! I need them to be as much as possible close to being even. So for 5 people I would aim to a 3:2 ratio rather than 4:1 or 5:0.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will suit your application, but you might be able to use an existing 'stratified sampling' function and then evaluate the outcome to see whether it satisfies your additional requirements, e.g.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("splitTools")
library(splitTools)

# set seed
set.seed(12345)

# create data
people <- data.frame(Name = paste("Name", 1:51),
                     Var1 = sample(c("A", "B"), 51, prob = c(0.3, 0.7), replace = TRUE),
                     Var2 = sample(1:2, 51, replace = TRUE))
table(people$Var1, people$Var2)

# proportion of "people" in each split
prop <- 1/9
inds <- partition(people$Var1, p = c(a = prop, b = prop, c = prop,
                                     d = prop, e = prop, f = prop,
                                     g = prop, h = prop, i = prop))
# split the patients (load dfs into a list)
dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:9){
  dfs[[i]] <- people[inds[[i]],]
}
# name the dfs
names(dfs) <- c("df_01", "df_02", "df_03", "df_04", "df_05",
                "df_06", "df_07", "df_08", "df_09")

# check requirements (at least 1 "A" in Var1)
for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
  if(!nrow(filter(dfs[[i]], Var1 == "A")) >= 1){
    print("error")
  }
}

# If no error, load dataframes into global environment
list2env(dfs, envir=.GlobalEnv)

df_01
#      Name Var1 Var2
#5   Name 5    B    1
#9   Name 9    A    1
#14 Name 14    B    1
#26 Name 26    B    2
#27 Name 27    B    2
#38 Name 38    A    1

df_02
#      Name Var1 Var2
#2   Name 2    A    2
#10 Name 10    A    1
#16 Name 16    B    1
#19 Name 19    B    2
#29 Name 29    B    1
#39 Name 39    B    1

df_03
#      Name Var1 Var2
#7   Name 7    B    1
#17 Name 17    B    1
#25 Name 25    B    2
#33 Name 33    B    2
#44 Name 44    A    2
#51 Name 51    A    1

df_04
#      Name Var1 Var2
#20 Name 20    A    2
#30 Name 30    B    2
#34 Name 34    B    1
#37 Name 37    A    2
#45 Name 45    B    2
#50 Name 50    B    1

df_05
#      Name Var1 Var2
#3   Name 3    A    1
#12 Name 12    B    2
#13 Name 13    A    1
#15 Name 15    B    1
#22 Name 22    B    1
#36 Name 36    B    1

df_06
#      Name Var1 Var2
#1   Name 1    A    1
#8   Name 8    B    1
#11 Name 11    B    2
#23 Name 23    A    2
#35 Name 35    B    1
#42 Name 42    B    2

df_07
#     Name Var1 Var2
#6   Name 6    B    1
#21 Name 21    B    1
#43 Name 43    A    1
#47 Name 47    B    1

df_08
#     Name Var1 Var2
#24 Name 24    A    1
#28 Name 28    B    1
#32 Name 32    B    1
#41 Name 41    A    1
#46 Name 46    B    2
#48 Name 48    B    2

df_09
#      Name Var1 Var2
#4   Name 4    A    1
#18 Name 18    B    1
#31 Name 31    A    1
#40 Name 40    B    1
#49 Name 49    B    2
```

This has the issue that "df_07" only has 4 rows, but if you change the seed - e.g. `set.seed(123)` - and run it again you get groups with at least one "A" and 5 or 6 rows in each.